# Query 2 MYSQL tables + condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

Format -> column.example_data

Table 1: id.1 | name.Joe | etc.Some | ...Other | ...Data

Table 2: id.X | number.+1 123 555 9999 | useridfromtable1.1 -> Linking telefone with Joe

Table 3: id. X | number.+1 123 555 9999 | calls.55

I need a query that join the 3 tables and I only have the id (userid) from the table 1.

So, I need from userid -> grab the telephone -> from the telefone grab calls on table3.

Comment: Im completely lost cause I have no idea how to do that query in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
SELECT t1.name,t1.id,t2.number,t3.calls
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.useridfromtable=t1.id
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.number = t2.number
```

Comment: Thank, worked perfectly. Any chance you know how can I print the sum of cals on the result? after all these join I get about 10 lines of the same user and their respective calls based on the phone, what is correct for what I asked, now I need return all the calls in 1 line with the values sum.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
SELECT t1.name,t1.id,t2.number,t3.calls
    FROM table1 t1
      INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
        INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.t2_id = t2.id
```

Where `t1_id` and `t2_id` are the fields that are referring the records in the *parent tables*. I recommend you to add an index on those fields also.

Comment: Thank, worked perfectly as well, tried both. Any chance you know how can I print the sum of cals on the result? after all these join I get about 10 lines of the same user and their respective calls based on the phone, what is correct for what I asked, now I need return all the calls in 1 line with the values sum.